# What is the custom url scheme to launch PhotoBooth on iOS?

Tags: ios, url

I wish to launch PhotoBooth on iOS from a webpage using a link. I believe the best way to do so is to use a custom url scheme. But I can't seem to find one for Photobooth documented anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes on iPad 2. I am unsure about iPhone

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about PhotoBooth, but **if you have a jailbroken device**, you would be able to reverse engineer what the URL scheme is (of any app).

1. `ssh` into your phone
2. navigate to the location where the app is installed (for example `/var/mobile/Applications/*/PhotoBooth.app`)
3. if you have the `plutil` utility installed (get from Cydia), then run `plutil Info.plist` on the plist file that's inside the PhotoBooth.app folder.
4. if you don't have `plutil`, then just `scp` the Info.plist file back to your Mac, and then open it with the OS X **Property List Editor** app.
5. inside the Info.plist you should find information about the custom URL scheme, if it supports one.
6. that will at least tell you if a custom URL scheme is supported, and a little about it.  from there, you might be in better position to do some more web searching

[See here for more information about what the Info.plist would have, regarding URL schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) (the example uses a `todolist://` protocol)